# CSS hide div with radiobutton outside form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to hide a div through css.
The div hide is working inside the form, how can this be done outside the form, or even outside the div row?

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="show" checked/>Show <br>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="hide"/>Hide

        <div class="hideDiv">
            <p>Can you see me</p>
        </div>
    </form>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
input[type=radio][value="hide"]:checked ~ .hideDiv {
    display: none;
}
```

Preferably only css but javascript is also a option.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work outside a form. As long both inputs and the element with hideDiv class share the same parent, it should work.

Comment: if my code helped please upvote :)

Comment: @MaxAlexanderHanna your code did help and I want to upvote, but I need more reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something similar to this code will help?

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="hideFunc();" value="show" checked/>Show <br> 
<input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="hideFunc();"  value="hide"/>Hide
<script>
hideFunc = function() {
   if (document.getElementsByClassName('hideDiv')[0].style.display == "none")
      document.getElementsByClassName('hideDiv')[0].style.display = "block";
   else
      document.getElementsByClassName('hideDiv')[0].style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use less CSS specificity.

```
.hideDiv {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

favorite

I am trying to hide a div through css. The div hide is working inside the form, how can this be done outside the form, or even outside the div row?

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="show" onclick="hideDiv();" checked/>Show <br>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="hideDiv();" value="hide"/>Hide

        <div class="hideDiv">
            <p>Can you see me</p>
        </div>
    </form>  
</div>
```

JS

```
function hideDiv() {
    var aux = $('input[name="radio"]:checked').val();
    if (aux == 'show'){
        $('.hideDiv').css("display","block");
    }else{
        $('.hideDiv').css("display","none");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice try thats not JS thats jQuery :)

Comment: Thats true. Heheh

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily using jquery

```js
$('.chkToogle').click(function(){
 $('.hideDiv').fadeToggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkToogle" checked/>Show/Hide
  </form>  
</div>
<div class="hideDiv">
 <p>Can you see me</p>
</div>
```